# How to show data from SQLite with CRUD in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Hi I'm doing an app and I made the database but I don't know how to read it to show in a listview for example I have a table CategoriaEntradas and I need to show all the data in a listview but I don't understand very well how it works all the classes

This is my Dao class

```
@Dao
public interface CategoriaEntradasDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas);

    @Update
    void update(CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas);

    @Delete
    void delete(CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas);

    @Query("DELETE FROM CategoriaEntradas")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CategoriaEntradas")
    LiveData<List<CategoriaEntradas>> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CategoriaEntradas WHERE IdCategoria =:Id")
    LiveData<CategoriaEntradas> getOne(int Id);
}
```

This is my Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "CategoriaEntradas")
public class CategoriaEntradas {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IdCategoria")
    private Integer _idCategoria;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Name")
    private String _name;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Image")
    private String _image;

    public CategoriaEntradas(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String image) { _name = name; _image = image;}

    public void set_idCategoria(Integer _idCategoria){
        this._idCategoria = _idCategoria;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Integer getIdCategoria() {
        return _idCategoria;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getImage() {
        return _image;
    }
}
```

My Repository class

```
public class CategoriaEntradasRepository {

    private CategoriaEntradasDao categoriaEntradasDao;
    private LiveData<List<CategoriaEntradas>> listLiveData;

    public CategoriaEntradasRepository(Application application) {
        Database db = Database.getDatabase(application);
        categoriaEntradasDao = db.categoriaEntradasDao();
        listLiveData = categoriaEntradasDao.getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<CategoriaEntradas>> getAll() {
        return listLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<CategoriaEntradas> getOne(int Id) {
        return categoriaEntradasDao.getOne(Id);
    }

    public void insert (CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas) {
        new CategoriaEntradasRepository.insertAsyncTask(categoriaEntradasDao).execute(categoriaEntradas);
    }


    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CategoriaEntradas, Void, Void> {

        private CategoriaEntradasDao entradasDao;

        insertAsyncTask(CategoriaEntradasDao dao) {
            entradasDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final CategoriaEntradas... params) {
            entradasDao.insert(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void update(final CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas){
         new CategoriaEntradasRepository.updateAsyncTask(categoriaEntradasDao).execute(categoriaEntradas);

    }

    private static class updateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CategoriaEntradas, Void, Void>{

        private CategoriaEntradasDao entradasDao;

        updateAsyncTask(CategoriaEntradasDao dao) {
            entradasDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final CategoriaEntradas... params){
            entradasDao.update(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void delete(final CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas) {

        new  CategoriaEntradasRepository.deleteAsyncTask(categoriaEntradasDao).execute(categoriaEntradas);
    }

    public void delete(final int Id) {

        final LiveData<CategoriaEntradas> categoriaEntradas = getOne(Id);
        if (categoriaEntradas != null) {
            new CategoriaEntradasRepository.deleteAsyncTask(categoriaEntradasDao).execute(categoriaEntradas.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static class deleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CategoriaEntradas, Void, Void>{

        private CategoriaEntradasDao entradasDao;

        deleteAsyncTask(CategoriaEntradasDao dao) {
            entradasDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final CategoriaEntradas... params){
            entradasDao.delete(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel class

```
public class CategoriaEntradasViewModel  extends AndroidViewModel {

    private CategoriaEntradasRepository repository;

    private LiveData<List<CategoriaEntradas>> listLiveData;

    public CategoriaEntradasViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new CategoriaEntradasRepository(application);
        listLiveData = repository.getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<CategoriaEntradas>> getAll() { return listLiveData; }

    public LiveData<CategoriaEntradas> getOne(int Id) { return repository.getOne(Id); }

    public void insert(CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas) { repository.insert(categoriaEntradas); }

    public void update(CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas){ repository.update(categoriaEntradas);}

    public void delete(CategoriaEntradas categoriaEntradas) {repository.delete(categoriaEntradas);}

    public void delete(int Id) {repository.delete(Id);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at your Activity or fragment that have your listview.

```
CategoriaEntradasViewModel mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoriaEntradasViewModel.class);

mViewModel.getAll().observe(this, new Observer<List<CategoriaEntradas>>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<CategoriaEntradas> categoriaEntradas) {

    adapter = new YourListViewAdapter(this, categoriaEntradas);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: What I have to put in YourListViewAdapter?

Comment: You have to put your custom adapter there.

Comment: So I have to creat a new one?

Comment: Yes, if you have custom list item view. Its similar to array adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have custom list item view. Its similar to array adapter.